# Combining Two Conditions in NSPredicate

Tags: swift, nspredicate

How do you combine two conditions in `NSPredicate`? I am using the following statement and I would like to add another condition that compares the the password with the contents of a textfield using **AND**:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username = %@", txtUserName.text!)
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try this

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username = %@ AND password = %@", txtUserName.text!, txtPassword.text!)
```

Answer (score 67):

As already said, you can use logical operators like "AND", "OR"
in predicates. Details can be found in 
[Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1) in the "Predicate Programming Guide".

As an alternative, use "compound predicates":

```
let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "username = %@", "user")
let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "password = %@", "password")
let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [p1, p2])
```

This is useful for more complex expressions, or if you want to build
a predicate dynamically at runtime.

Comment: What if I need OR  condition ?

Comment: @Jan: `orPredicateWithSubpredicates` ?

Comment: What if both need something like NSPredicate(format: "(username = %@ AND password = %@)) OR (email = %@ AND password = %@) ", usernameAndEmail, txtPassword.text!,usernameAndEmail, txtPassword.text!)

Comment: @John: You can write a single  predicate with "AND" and "OR", or combine simple predicates using  andPredicateWithSubpredicates/orPredicateWithSubpredicates – both methods work.

Answer (score 1):

`AND` is exactly what you need

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username = %@ AND password = %@", txtUserName.text!, txtPassWord.text!)
```