# Combining 2 values into a NSPredicate

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift3, nspredicate

I'm trying to do a fetch request that checks for 2 things.

Here is my Data:

Person - entity
Statement - entity
The Person entity has a relationship to statements as To Many. The statement entity has an attribute called amountOwed. This is the property I want to check in the predicate.

**EDIT**
What I am trying to do is this. 
Check all of my Persons entities for a name, lets say Bob.

Once I find the Bob entity I want to check all of his Statement entities for an attribute called amountOwed and see if it's greater or less then 0.

1. Check for a name in the Person Entity. When that name matches, use that entity.
2. Check if the amountOwed in a Statement entity is greater or less then 0.

This is what I have been trying to get to work.

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"name == %@ AND @statement.amountOwed >= 0", personName))
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Person.name), ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
positiveFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

do {
    try positiveFetchedResultsController.performFetch()
} catch let error as NSError{
    print("Fetching error: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'
```

I found the AND method here: [using AND link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321050/combining-two-conditions-in-nspredicate)

**Edit**
[image]

Comment: Why does nobody read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html)? ;-)

Comment: The error is "to-many key not allowed here.". There is only one to-many key in your predicate: "statement.amountOwed >= 0".  So the error is saying "each Person can have many statements - which one should I use?  The one with the maximum amountOwed?  Or the minimum?  Or the amountOwed on any statement?  Or check the amountOwed on all the statements?  Or (as I think you mean) add up the amountOwed for all the related statements.  If it is the last, use `fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"name == %@ AND statement.@sum.amountOwed >= 0", personName)`.

Comment: I'm trying to display all the statements for each person, and divide those between negative and positive numbers and then display each FRC in a section of a tableView. Does that make sense?

Comment: To clarify, your table view will display the statements for a single Person.  Each row will represent a single Statement (for that Person).  There will be two sections; one showing the Statements with +ve amountOwed, and one showing Statements with -ve amountOwed.  If that's right, what order would you like the rows in?

Comment: That is correct. The rows can be in any order. If it's easier to display them from largest to smallest thats fine. The important thing is that each section of the table view display proplerly. One section for positive amounts and one section for negative amounts.

Answer (score 1):

You should build your FRC to fetch `Statement` objects, not `Person` objects:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Statement> = Statement.fetchRequest()
```

Assuming the `statement` relationship has an inverse (to-one) relationship named `person`, then you can use the following predicate to ensure you fetch only the statements with a positive `amountOwed` relating to a person with a given name:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"person.name == %@ AND amountOwed >= 0", personName)
```

(and similarly for the negative `amountOwed`).  Specify sort descriptors to get whatever sort order you wish.  Your FRCs' `fetchedObjects` arrays will then contain `Statement` objects which you can use to populate the table view: the positive FRC for section 0 and negative FRC for section 1 (or vice versa).

NB. because you are fetching the `Statement` objects, it is possible to achieve what you want with just one FRC - but only if you are happy with the statements being sorted by `amountOwed` (ascending or descending).  If you wish to do this, I can provide further detail.

Comment: Hi I tried to implement your idea on my own. It's not working so I would very much appreciate further details on your idea. It doesn't seem to be finding the entities with the name in the predicate.

Comment: I'll update my answer later today - in the meantime, please can you post a picture of your data model?  Thanks.

Comment: Let me know if that is what you were looking for from my data model.

Comment: My fetch request comes back with 0, even though I know there is one saved.

Comment: OK.  Remove the predicate, run the fetch then print the results.  Check the "person" property for the Statements that you fetch, then check "person.name".

Comment: So these 2 print statements worked when I removed the predicate.  `print("\(positiveFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects![0].person) this is the person")

        print("\(positiveFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects![0].person!.name) this is the name of the person")`

Comment: Does the predicate return an optional for the name value? `format:"person.name == %@ AND amountOwed >= 0", personName` When I printed it, I had to force unwrap the name. `positiveFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects![0].person!.name`

Comment: Does the name match what you would expect?  (Double check capitalisation and trailing spaces).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131625/discussion-between-icekomo-and-pbasdf).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSPredicate(format:"name == %@ AND statement.@amountOwed >= 0", personName)
```

The `AND` has to be part of the string as the example you attached...

Comment: Do I need the @ in front of the attribute amountOwed? Should it be: `fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"name == %@ AND statement.amountOwed >= 0",personName)`. When I try either way I get an error.   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here

Comment: Is it a variable in your code? Try like this NSPredicate(format:"name == %@ AND %@ >= 0", personName, statement.amountOwed)

Comment: no the amount owed is an attribute for the entity of Statement. The Person entity that I am fetching can have multiple Statement entities linked to it. So I'm trying to fetch a person by name, and then look at all of their Statement entities.

Comment: I'm not experienced in that, but the AND has to be inside the format string. Good luck